# Python `logging` module + YAML config file

Tags: python, logging, config

I have found a lot of documentation and tutorials such as the [official `logging` config docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/logging.config.html#logging-config-api), the [official `logging` cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-cookbook), and this [nice tutorial by Fang](https://fangpenlin.com/posts/2012/08/26/good-logging-practice-in-python/).

Each of them have gotten me near to an answer, but not quite.  My question is this:

## When using Config Files, how can I use a logger with 2 separate handlers at 2 separate levels?

---

To clarify, here is an example of my YAML file:

```
---
version: 1
handlers:
  debug_console:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    level: DEBUG
.
.
.

  info_file_handler:
    class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
    level: INFO
.
.
.

loggers:
  dev:
    handlers: [debug_console, info_file_handler]
  test:
    handlers: [info_file_handler]
root:
  handlers: [info_file_handler]
```

I want to have **two ways** to run the logger, where one way (`dev`) is more verbose than the other.  **Moreover, when running the `dev` logger, I want it to have two different levels for the two different handlers.**

This is a snippet of the code to try to launch the logger:

```
with open('logging.yaml', 'r') as f:
  log_cfg = yaml.safe_load(f.read())
  logging.config.dictConfig(log_cfg)
  my_logger = logging.getLogger('dev')
```

---

The `dictConfig` line above works correctly.  I say this because when I get to the code which asks to log to the console, I will see `dev` as the name when the log prints out.  (I have edited the yaml, but it contains `%(name)s` in the format.)

But there is something wrong with `my_logger`.  **Even though** it is tied to the *name* of `dev`, none of the rest of the attributes seem to have been set.  Specifically, I see:

```
>>> my_logger
<Logger dev_model (WARNING)>
```

I don't know the `logging` module well enough to understand where the problem is.  What I *want* is:

#### When I activate the `'dev'` logger, I want to launch 2 handlers, one which is at the `DEBUG` level and writes to console, the other which is at the `INFO` level and writes to a file.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, the problem is caused by the fact the logger itself has a log level, not just handlers. Logger's log level defaults to `WARNING`, which seems to be set on your logger. If a generated message has a lower priority than the logger's level then it does not even make to the handlers.

So try setting logger's `level` to `DEBUG`. `info_file_handler` should ignore any messages more verbose than it's own level.

As for this part:

> none of the rest of the attributes seem to have been set.

What happens there is logger's `repr()` method is called to convert Logger to some sort of string representation in order to render it. Which is not guaranteed to show all the attributes of the object.

Comment: Wow!  That's it, @dvk!  I was hoping it was something this simple.  I *assumed* that if I didn't set the `level` on the `logger`, the level would match that of the `handler`.  Not so!  If I may ask a follow-up?  Why not just put either `NOTSET` or `DEBUG` on all of my `logger`s since what I really want is to set that level at all of my handlers?  I know it will work, but is this considered bad practice?  Is there a "gotcha" I might be missing?  Thanks!

Comment: I am not aware of any issues with setting logger levels to not set / debug. The idea behind the logger level is being able to control what the logger outputs with a single knob. And handler levels allow you to fine-tune this per handler - for the stuff that passes the logger level check. If you want all messages to get to the handlers then just pass the debug / not set level to loggers as you suggest

Answer (score 0):

Such a long question... Too long for me to understand well.

But I think you misunderstand how handlers work. Actually logger itself doesn't output anything but handlers do.

So let's say if you set `DEBUG` on `dev` logger, it will pass logs >= `DEBUG` to all handlers. And then `debug_console` handler will process logs >= `DEBUG` but `info_file_handler` will only process logs >= `INFO`. Setting `DEBUG` on `dev` logger won't let `info_file_handler` output logs < `INFO`. So you do can have two separate levels which one is >= `DEBUG` and goes to console while another is >= `INFO` and goes to file.

I am presuming I understand you rightly...

Comment: Hi @Sraw yes, you are understanding me correctly.  And I **thought** I set it up to do precisely that.  Can you please provide a code snippet to explain how to set it up?  Every example I've found simply **stops** when it comes to actually launching and implementing the logger.